# How to query relationships in Laravel 4 with Eloquent?

Tags: codeigniter, orm, laravel, eloquent

Coming from CodeIgniter's Datamapper ORM I am still trying to get my head around Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

Given the fact that I have an ACCOUNT and a USER table (simplified):

```
ACCOUNT
- id
- name

USER
- id
- account_id
- username
```

One account has many users. One user belongs to one account. So we're dealing with a one-to-many relationship. Everything is already set-up in the models.

In CodeIgniter's Datamapper I would have done the following to get the user from any given ID and at the same time check if that user is related to the current account:

```
$u = new User();
$u->where('username', $username);
$u->where_related_account('id', $account_id);
$u->get();

if ( ! $u->exists()) exit; // or do something...

// otherwise continue to use the "$u" user object
```

This syntax is very logical and easy to understand. In Eloquent I have a hard time to achieve the same with a similar easy syntax. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Very simply (ignoring the relationship between the user and the account), it could just be:

```
$u = User::where('username', $username)
         ->where('account_id', $id)
         ->get();
```

That will return you your user's details.

Otherwise, assuming that you have your User and Account classes and DB tables are set up correctly ([as per the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many)), you should be able to just do:

```
$user_exists = Account::find($account_id)
                      ->users()
                      ->where("username", "=", $username)
                      ->first()
                      ->exists;

if ($user_exists)
{
    doThings();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've correctly set up your models and database tables (as @msturdy said) you should actually be able to return your user account by simply going:

```
$user = User::whereUsername($username)
            ->first(); // or User::where('username', $username)->first();
if ($user) {
    $account = $user->accounts()
                        ->whereId($account_id)
                        ->first(); // or $user->accounts()->where('id', $account_id)->first();
}
```

This gives you the ability to access the user and account models

you could even extend your `User` model to include the following methods:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public static function byUsername($username) {
        return static::whereUsername($username)->first();
    }

    public function getAccount($id) {
        return $this->accounts()->whereId($id)->first();
    }

    ...

}
```

and then simply go

```
$user = User::byUsername($username);
if ($user) {
    $account = $user->getAccount($account_id);
}
```

which might be better for you if you are using the code in multiple controllers.